# Embedded MongoDB Document not getting an ID on save with C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When I have a root document that has a list of documents and I save/insert, the root document always gets an ID from MongoDB, but the documents in the list don't, they remain the same as `ObjectId.Empty`. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if this is intended behavior?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
Given the classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

With a Factory:

```
public class Factory
{
    public Foo CreateFoo(string name)
    {
        return new Foo {
            Id = new ObjectId(),
            Name = name,
            Bars = new List<Bar>()
        };
    }

    public Bar CreateBar(string name)
    {
        return new Bar {
            Id = new ObjectId(),
            Name = name
        };
    }
}
```

When I run a sample like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("Example1");
        if (!database.CollectionExists("foos")) database.CreateCollection("foos");

        var factory = new Factory();
        var foo1 = factory.CreateFoo("first");
        foo1.Bars.Add(factory.CreateBar("bar"));
        var collection = database.GetCollection("foos");
        collection.Insert(foo1);

        var foo2 = factory.CreateFoo("second");
        collection.Insert(foo2);
        foo2.Bars.Add(factory.CreateBar("bar"));
        collection.Save(foo2);
    }
}
```

Both `foo1` and `foo2` get `_id`'s generated by MongoDB, but none of the `Bars` do. All the `Bars` still have the `ObjectId.Empty`. Now an easy solution is to update the factory to use `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()`, but I'd feel more comfortable with it being generated from the DB. Does anyone have any insight on this? Am I doing something wrong? Is this even possible? Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver will only generate the Id field for you when the fields is identified as the `_id` of a collection. In your case, `Bar` is embedded inside the `Foo` document.

Therefore, it doesn't make sense for `Bar` to have an auto-generated Id field.

In your example, there is really no reason for `Bar` to have a unique `_id`. When you query the collection, you will query based on the `_id` of `Foo` and you'll have `Bar` objects available in the response.

This is definitely intended behavior.

Comment: If I need to delete an item, how should I act?

Answer (score 1):

It's intended behaviour.  Each document (not sub-document) has an _id which get assigned automatically if empty.

You either need to have a separate collection of Bars and reference it from the Foo documents, or manually generate the ObjectIds.

If you're doing it from a factory [ or repository ] then it would be solid.

EDIT:

Also, if you use

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
string Id {get;set;}
```

It means you can access the objectId value more easily, it would still be saved of ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

There is one frequent scenario to update or remove one element of the embeded document collection. The only way is to rely on the id.

At the moment I have built a customised IIdGenerator  and have assigned it to the IdMemberMap, but it only gets called for the root document.

Is there any other way to generate automatic ids for embeded documents?