# MongoDB C# how to generate an object ID to a nested element inside an element

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm looking for a way to generate an ObjectId for a nested inner attribute using MongoDB c# driver. Unfortunately, it won't generate the id for the inner collection. I'm looking for a way to automatically generate an Id

Entity Class

```
public class BigTree : IEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Revision { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Dejavu> Dejavu { get; set; }
}

public interface IEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public class Dejavu : IEntity
{
    public Dejavu()
    {
        Delgo = new Delgo();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public Delgo Delgo { get; set; }
}
```

Mapper class

```
public static void MapAllTheClasses ()
{
    MapEntity<BigTree>();
    MapEntity<Delgo>();
    MapEntity<Dejavu>();     
}

public static void MapEntity<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
{
    BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<TEntity>( e =>
     {
         e.AutoMap();
         e.MapIdProperty( u => u.Id )
                  .SetIdGenerator( StringObjectIdGenerator.Instance )
                  .SetSerializer( new StringSerializer( BsonType.ObjectId ) );
     } );
}
```

Result

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('56386cc49aa56e25d46aa279'),
    "ProjectId": "56386fa24ff36e25d46aa276",
    "Name": "alpha",
    "Dejavu": [
        {
            "FieldName": "apple",
            "LK003": {
                "Qty": 1,
                "Content": "red"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically generate ObjectId for the main `_id` of the collection, you have to mark Id property with attributes:

```
[BsonId]
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
public string Id { get; set; }
```

However, according to [that answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678718/embedded-mongodb-document-not-getting-an-id-on-save-with-c-sharp-driver), you should consider your approach because automatically generated Id of the nested elements in the collection doesn't make sense.

> You either need to have a separate collection of Dejavu and reference it from the BigTree documents, or manually generate the ObjectIds.

Comment: hello, I'm using the same annotations, but I see _id as null in my database

Comment: It will not work like mentioned in this answer, but it could work if we write a custom serializer.